# JavaScript RegEx double name

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to only allow one capital letter at start, and one more if(after hyphen) and that your able to write only one hyphen, so that u can write a double name, like Klas-Bertil and nothing else.

Shall allow:

```
Klas
Klas-Bertil
Fredrick-Patrick
```

not:

```
KlAs-
KLaS-bErtIl
Fre-Dr-IckP-aTrick
```

Dont know if im making myself understood? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any experience with regular expressions at all? Is there a possibility that a name might include unicode characters?

Comment: Strictly validating names is generally not a very good idea, people have the darnest names.

Comment: @adeneo old McDonald agrees

Comment: I have no experience at all. Im swedish and its quite common with double names here, so i wanted the user to be able to write their name in, as i would type Alexander, they would type Clas-Bertil etc, but im beginning to suspect i got water over my head here and I might just allow [A-Za-z-] and be done with it :)  // I do appreciate the answers!

Comment: Living in sweden, you'd expect names like `Abdul-Raafi' al-Hussein`, `Mohamed ElBaradei`, and what about å, ä, ö etc. `Albert Åberg`. Validating names is, again, generally not a very good idea.

Comment: ^[a-zåäöA-ZÅÄÖ-]$ i have this atm, its only for a school project and im allready in to deep, i get what ur saying and ill keep that in mind in the future, not limiting the user ofc is the best way to go at it. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
^[A-Z]?[a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)?$
```

if you'd like to force capital letter at the start:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)?$
```

Comment: Didn't make that work, thanks thou! its js for an <input> field and im not experienced enough to tell you why it didn't work.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have the simplest RegEx for the name parts, like this

```
var regEx = /^[A-Z][a-z]*$/;
```

This will match any string which starts with zero or more white space characters, followed by a capital letter, followed by a string of small letters and ends with zero or more characters.

Now, split the input string with `-` and apply the `regEx` on all of them to see if all the parts match or not.

```
var regEx = /^[A-Z][a-z]*$/;

function isInitCapNames(name) {
    return name.split("-").every(function(currentPart) {
        return regEx.test(currentPart);
    });
}
```

Test cases:

```
console.assert(isInitCapNames('Klas') === true);
console.assert(isInitCapNames('Klas-Bertil') === true);
console.assert(isInitCapNames('Fredrick-Patrick') === true);
console.assert(isInitCapNames('KlAs-') === false);
console.assert(isInitCapNames('KLaS-bErtIl') === false);
console.assert(isInitCapNames('Fre-Dr-IckP-aTrick') === false);
```

Comment: I see were this is going! I might haveto do as u recommend, im not sure what i wanted to achive with my question but ill try and change my code abit and perheps this will come in handy ;) thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

```
/^([A-Z]{1,1})([a-z]+)-([A-Z]{1,1})([a-z])$/
```

Comment: Didn't make that work, thanks thou! its js for an <input> field and im not experienced enough to tell you why it didn't work.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of restricting the users, just fix their input? would be much more convenient for both sides i believe:

```js
var names = ["KlAs-","KLaS-bE$@rtIl-banana","Fre-Dr-IckP-aTrick","Klas","Klas-Bertil","Fredrick-Patrick"]

function FixName(name){
    //remove all special characters from the name
    name = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/g,'');
    //check for hyphens and only get 1 of those, takes 2 name parts.
    var name_parts = name.split('-',2);
    //fix the first name part
    var Fixed_Name=(name_parts[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name_parts[0].slice(1).toLowerCase()).trim();
    //check if there is anything after the hyphen, and fix it too.
    if(name_parts[1].trim()!=""){
        Fixed_Name+="-"+(name_parts[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name_parts[1].slice(1).toLowerCase()).trim();
    }
    alert(Fixed_Name);
}

FixName(names[1]);
```

Comment: I really appriciate your answer! Not the direction I was going but perhaps ill change my mind :)

Comment: you could always perform more checks according to possible valid names, and each time improve the fixing function. restricting the user can be very annoying, if the website tells you every time that your input is no good and that you need to change it, you would eventually give up no? :)

Comment: true! was just trying to control it the "best" way, atleast what i though was the best way ;) ill have the user be able to write A-Za-z and - , then if i haveto, ill apply a filter, im currently studying Javadevelopment (dno if correct translate) in sweden and im allready to deep in our webdesign course, but i haveto follow the rabbit ;) Tanks again!

Comment: an easier way for you might be to make a custom keydown handler for your input, monitor for characters typed on the keyboard and simply restrict the use of special characters in the input box.